# Solr stop words not working

Tags: search, solr, stop-words

I'm working on a predictive search using Solr 3.6.
I need the Solr to ignore the word "con " (with the whitespace) that means "with " in spanish
I added the solr.StopFilterFactory:

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"    // I also tried with "false"
                />
```

and my file only contains "con " (without the quotes)

but when I search "Departamento con parrilla" Solr doesn´t return anything and I need it to return "Departamento parrilla" ignoring the word "con " in the query

I hope I made myself understood.

Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: can you paste the whole analyzer definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, I wasn't assigning the correct FieldType to the field I wanted to be filtered.